# GraphDB 10.3 exception on SPARQL query: "Bad IRI string: id 3139, type -1 --> iriString null (HTTP status 500)"

Tags: sparql, graphdb

In trying to run the following query on GraphDB 10.3:

```
PREFIX p: <http://www.example.com/ontology/xyz/>

select * where {
  values ?s { p:abc }
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

It gives the following error:

> Error 500: error
> Query evaluation error: Bad IRI string: id 3139, type -1 --> iriString null (HTTP status 500)

NB: The prefix has been modified so it can be posted.

If the prefix is changed, the query returns an empty result set.

The query above gives the following exception:

```
11:01:32.703 [repositories/internal] INFO  c.o.g.s.h.GraphDBQueryResultHandler - POST query -376037858
11:01:32.709 [repositories/internal] ERROR c.o.g.sesame.TupleQueryResultView - Query evaluation error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad IRI string: id 3139, type -1 --> iriString null
    at com.ontotext.trree.entitypool.impl.storage.DatatypeLanguageSet.getDatatype(DatatypeLanguageSet.java:97)
    at com.ontotext.trree.entitypool.impl.storage.EntityTypeStorage.getDatatype(EntityTypeStorage.java:125)
    at com.ontotext.trree.entitypool.impl.TransactionalEntityPool$TransactionalEntityPoolConnection.toObjectStoredEntity(TransactionalEntityPool.java:1261)
    at com.ontotext.trree.entitypool.impl.TransactionalEntityPool$TransactionalEntityPoolConnection.getValue(TransactionalEntityPool.java:364)
    at com.ontotext.trree.entitypool.impl.CustomValue.retrieveValue(CustomValue.java:42)
    at com.ontotext.trree.entitypool.impl.CustomLiteralImpl.getCoreDatatype(CustomLiteralImpl.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.util.Literals.isLanguageLiteral(Literals.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.sparqljson.AbstractSPARQLJSONWriter.writeValue(AbstractSPARQLJSONWriter.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.sparqljson.SPARQLResultsJSONWriter.writeValue(SPARQLResultsJSONWriter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.sparqljson.AbstractSPARQLJSONWriter.handleSolutionImpl(AbstractSPARQLJSONWriter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.AbstractQueryResultWriter.handleSolution(AbstractQueryResultWriter.java:71)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.CatchHandler.processWithBuffer(CatchHandler.java:131)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.sesame.TupleQueryResultView.renderInternal(TupleQueryResultView.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.QueryResultView.render(QueryResultView.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:352)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.audit.AuditRequestCacheFilter.doFilterInternal(AuditRequestCacheFilter.java:26)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.ExtendedAnonymousFilter.doFilter(ExtendedAnonymousFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.stateless.GDBTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(GDBTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.stateless.GDBSignatureAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(GDBSignatureAuthenticationFilter.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.audit.AuditLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AuditLoggingFilter.java:22)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:225)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:190)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at com.ontotext.forest.clusterproxy.ClusterFilterBean.doFilter(ClusterFilterBean.java:73)
    at com.ontotext.forest.clusterproxy.ClusterLoadBalancerFilter.doFilterInternal(ClusterLoadBalancerFilter.java:25)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at com.ontotext.forest.core.request.RequestFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestFilter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
11:01:32.710 [repositories/internal] INFO  c.o.g.sesame.TupleQueryResultView - Request for query -376037858 is finished
```

Comment: the error messages sounds more like some literals in your RDF data do have some weird IRIs - can you say something about your data? Do you have literals with custom datatypes?

Comment: I have changed ?super -> ?s. Still gives the same error unless the prefix is modified. There are no custom data types.

Comment: I agree with UninformedUser. There's nothing wrong with your query. Problem is probably in the data.